# I view sth [as/to be] the most

Tags: word-choice

Example:

> I view electricity **as/to be** the most important invention in the history of mankind.

Which of these is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct. The former sounds a notch less formal.

Comment: "view" is also not necessarily a preferred synonym for "think" or "consider", plus "think" allows "I think electricity is the most ... " which wins on conciseness.

Comment: You do have a point. "do" is not really necessary here, though.